# Get base url for preview build in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I am deploying a preview build through firebase hosting that is generating a url with some random characters, e.g. `https://my-app--preview-3wrm825h.web.app`.

Part of my website includes letting users copy a link to share with others. I would like to test this feature in the preview environments I deploy, but I do not know how to generate a link based on the base URL of the preview build. E.g. in the above example I would want to generate the following link: `https://my-app--preview-3wrm825h.web.app/my-link`

`process.env.PUBLIC_URL` returns an empty string. I could use `window.location.href` but this seems like a hack? Is there nowhere this base url is stored in my build that I can then reference?

I'm also using react-router if that helps.

Comment: check the Outputs https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-firebase-hosting, might help